# Spring boot load test: some requests stuck

Tags: spring, spring-boot, embedded-jetty, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm load testing spring boot application with embed jetty/tomcat and I got strange behaviour. I use apache ab for testing

```
ab -n 100000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1:8080/ping

Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /ping
Document Length:        2 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   5.253 seconds
Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      17000000 bytes
HTML transferred:       200000 bytes
Requests per second:    19038.05 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       52.526 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.053 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3160.61 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   37 222.1      0    3006
Processing:     0    7  21.9      3     855
Waiting:        0    7  21.7      3     853
Total:          0   44 228.0      4    3052

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      4
  66%      7
  75%      9
  80%     11
  90%     22
  95%     39
  98%   1004
  99%   1017
 100%   3052 (longest request)
```

So some request are stuck somewhere.
With jetty I tried different values of:

```
_maxThreads, _minThread
```

with tomcat:

```
max-connections, max-threads, min-spare-threads
```

In profiler I found the next:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run()                16,215ms
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800
        org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.iddleJobPoll
            org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll            13,915ms
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I truly understand what makes you think that some request are stuck somewhere?

Comment: hi. why 98% is 1s? 98 % of requeseets is ok. but 2 % got lot of time. Something strange. with -k(keepAlive) options result is better

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer. Some problems occurred every 30s.

[load test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZS4l.png)

This happened due to "server:tomcat:background-processor-delay" param.